# WPF: Navigation Service Object Instance Error

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF and have attempted to look and try different solutions:
I need to navigate to another page: From Page called `MainFrame` to `Page1`.

Error messages:

```
WPF does not containt a definition for navigation service.
```

Or

```
Object not set to instance of Object.
```

I tried this:

```
    private void CloseApplication_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        navService.Navigate(new Uri ("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Then I tried this, thinkinig something needs to instantiate on page load:

```
    NavigationService navService;

    public MainFrame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void MainFrame_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        navService = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
    }

    private void CloseApplication_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        navService.Navigate(new Uri ("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Comment: at least you should tell what error it is.

Comment: you can always access to the `NavigationService` instance using the property `NavigationService`, all `NavigationWindow`, `Frame` and `Page` do have that property.

Answer (score 0):

Use NavigationService instance in Page. Read [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx) article regarding Navigation

```
private void CloseApplication_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri ("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be pretty simple. The navigation happens in the **NavigationWindow** within **Pages** see example below:

First of all your main window should be inherited from a **NavigationWindow** class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : NavigationWindow
{
   public MainWindow()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
}
```

then the xaml must have a **NavigationWindow** root element:

```
<NavigationWindow x:Class="NavigationApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window" Height="300" Width="300" Source="MainPage.xaml">

</NavigationWindow>
```

This root element cannot contain any UI elements, as they are placed in pages. The root element contains a starting page attribute MainPage.xaml

```
<Page x:Class="NavigationApp.MainPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <Frame Source="Page2.xaml"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

In my case it contains a frame to a Page2.xaml which has only one button.

```
<Page x:Class="NavigationApp.Page2"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="Page2">

    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Navigate to page 1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="109,143,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

By clicking on that button it navigate to another page:

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    Uri uri = new Uri("Page1.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    NavigationService.Navigate(uri);
 }
```